# Malloc to a CGPoint Pointer throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing

Tags: iphone, c, uikit, core-foundation

I am trying to use a snippet of code from a Apple programming guide, and I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to pass a pointer to a function, right after doing a malloc.

(For Reference: [iPhone Application Programming Guide: Event Handling - Listing 3-6](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/EventHandling/EventHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW14))

The code in question is really simple:

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef touchBeginPoints;
UITouch *touch;

....

CGPoint *point = (CGPoint *)CFDictionaryGetValue(touchBeginPoints, touch);

if (point == NULL)
{
    point = (CGPoint *)malloc(sizeof(CGPoint));
    CFDictionarySetValue(touchBeginPoints, touch, point);
}
```

Now when the program goes into the `if` statement it assigns the 'output' of `malloc` into the `point` variable/pointer.

Then when it tries to pass `point` into the `CFDictionarySetValue` function it crashes the application with: `Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.`

Someone suggested not doing the `malloc` and pass the `point` var/pointer as: `&point`, however that still gave me a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

What I am (and it looks like Apple) doing wrong???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sean's answer is mostly correct.  According to [the documentation for `CFDictionarySetValue`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/corefoundation/reference/CFMutableDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001497-CH201-F11048), it's going to try and `retain` the value according to how your `CFMutableDictionaryRef` is set up.  I'm guessing that when you create the mutable dictionary (presumably using `CFDictionaryCreateMutable()`), you're not providing custom callbacks for [how to handle setting and removing values](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/corefoundation/reference/CFDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CFDictionaryValueCallBacks).

EDIT:

Another option to providing custom callbacks is to provide `NULL` for the value callbacks:

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, NULL);

CGPoint * point = (CGPoint *)malloc(sizeof(CGPoint));
point->x = 42;
point->y = 42;

CFDictionarySetValue(dict, @"foo", point);


CGPoint * newPoint = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, @"foo");
NSLog(@"%f, %f", newPoint->x, newPoint->y);
```

Logs:

```
2010-06-17 11:32:47.942 EmptyFoundation[45294:a0f] 42.000000, 42.000000
```

Comment: I didn't do custom call backs... I used the following...

touchBeginPoints = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

Comment: @kdbdallas and the documentation for `kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks` says that the default `retain` callback is `CFRetain`, which is where your problem lies.  You have to specify custom `retain` and `release` callbacks (and it wouldn't hurt to specify `copy` and `equals` callbacks either), or box the points in `NSValues`, like Dave Dribin suggests.

Comment: Defining it like this solved it. touchBeginPoints = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, NULL); THANKS!

Comment: Doesn't this leak the malloc'ed `CGPoint`?  When does it get freed?

Comment: @Dave yeah, this will leak both the point and the dictionary.  I was just writing the code to show that it's possible.

Comment: While it's easy to avoid leaking the dictionary, it's not easy to avoid leaking the CGPoint. You have to use a custom callback, but even then free() doesn't have the same semantics as CFRelease().  You can't call free() more than once, for example.

Answer (score 2):

CGPoint is a struct, not an Objective-C/CF object, so you need to wrap it in an `NSValue`:

`+ (NSValue *)valueWithPoint:(NSPoint)aPoint`

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSValue/valueWithPoint:

Comment: This would solve the problem, but the listing he links to in the question shows the `CGPoint*` getting added directly to the dictionary, without boxing it.  Unfortunately, the listing also fails to show how the `CFMutableDictionaryRef` was created.

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure that listing is completely wrong. There's no way to store a CG/NSPoint directly in a CF/NSDictionary.

Comment: @Dave Dribin you can store points in a `CFDictionary` just fine.  Look at the example in my post.  You just have to tell the dictionary to not try to retain the values (which is easily accomplished in the CFDictionary creation functions).

Comment: Yea it works as long as you setup the CFMutableDictionary correctly. Apple left that part out, and how I created it was wrong

Comment: @Dave DeLong. Sorry, you are correct for CFDictionary.  Seems like more trouble than it's worth. I'd just us an `NSMutableDictionary` and `NSValues`.

Comment: @Dave I probably would too, but I can imagine there are valid use-cases for wanting to avoid the overhead of boxing the points.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably crashing because it is trying to retain your CGPoint when you put it in the dictionary except CGPoint isn't a real object but instead a C structure.